# Share link and text with iOS Facebook SDK 3.x

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, facebook

I want to know if it's possible to share a custom text with link on Facebook using Facebook APICalls.

I've been trying for some time with this code

```
FBSession *session;
if (!session.isOpen) {
    session = [[FBSession alloc] init];
    [FBSession setActiveSession:session];
    if (appDelegate.session.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {
        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"publish_stream", nil]
                                           defaultAudience: FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone
                                              allowLoginUI: NO
                                         completionHandler: ^(FBSession *session,
                                                              FBSessionState status,
                                                              NSError *error)
         {}];
    }
}
[FBSettings setLoggingBehavior:[NSSet setWithObjects:FBLoggingBehaviorFBRequests, FBLoggingBehaviorFBURLConnections, nil]];

if (session.state != FBSessionStateCreated) {
    session = [[FBSession alloc] init];
    [FBSession setActiveSession:session];
}
[session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                     FBSessionState status,
                                     NSError *error) {
if (session.state != FBSessionStateCreated) {
    session = [[FBSession alloc] init];
    [FBSession setActiveSession:session];
}
NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test %@",[NSDate date]];
[session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                     FBSessionState status,
                                     NSError *error) {
    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test %@",[NSDate date]];
    [FBDialogs presentOSIntegratedShareDialogModallyFrom:self initialText:message image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fullCup"] url:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.m-Diet.com"] handler:^(FBOSIntegratedShareDialogResult result, NSError *error) {
        NSString *message = @"mDiet";
        NSString *link = @"http://www.m-Diet.com";
        NSString *description = @"برنامج حمية متطور";
        NSString *picture = @"http://www.m-diet.com/images/light-logo.png";
        NSMutableDictionary *tParams = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        message,     @"message",
                                        link,        @"link",
                                        description, @"description",
                                        picture,     @"picture", nil];
        [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:message parameters:tParams HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
            [self showAlert:@"Photo Post" result:result error:error];

        }];
    }];
}];
[FBSettings setLoggingBehavior:[NSSet setWithObjects:FBLoggingBehaviorFBRequests, FBLoggingBehaviorFBURLConnections, nil]];
}];
[FBSettings setLoggingBehavior:[NSSet setWithObjects:FBLoggingBehaviorFBRequests, FBLoggingBehaviorFBURLConnections, nil]];
```

But it continue giving me this error !!

```
2014-01-12 16:16:26.881 mDiet[4541:a0b] FBSDKLog: FBURLConnection <#1131>:
  Duration: 340 msec
Response Size: 0 kB
  MIME type: application/json
2014-01-12 16:16:26.881 mDiet[4541:a0b] FBSDKLog: Error: HTTP status code: 400
2014-01-12 16:16:26.882 mDiet[4541:a0b] FBSDKLog: Response <#1128> <Error>:
The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)
{
    "com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey" = "<FBSession: 0xcdaad30, state: FBSessionStateOpen, loginHandler: 0xcde6ac0, appID: 288500927926192, urlSchemeSuffix: , tokenCachingStrategy:<FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy: 0xcdcf7f0>, expirationDate: 2014-03-13 14:07:04 +0000, refreshDate: 2014-01-12 14:16:25 +0000, attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(\n    installed,\n    \"basic_info\",\n    \"public_profile\",\n    \"user_friends\"\n)>";
    "com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode" = 400;
    "com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey" =     (
                {
            body =             {
                error =                 {
                    code = 10;
                    message = "(#10) Application does not have permission for this action";
                    type = OAuthException;
                };
            };
            code = 400;
        }
    );
}
```

this is the permissions in the session

```
(
    "create_note",
    "basic_info",
    "share_item",
    "status_update",
    "user_friends",
    "publish_actions",
    "publish_checkins",
    "video_upload",
    "publish_stream",
    "photo_upload",
    installed,
    "public_profile"
)
```

Is it possible to share a custom link with Facebook API?